# React vs GWT for large scale web application

Tags: java, reactjs, gwt

As Java developer, I always felt comfortable developing web applications using **GWT**, but every now and then I am trying to check if there is a better framework that I can use for developing a large scale web application.
I tried out [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/), and I liked it, but as a Java developer I am not feeling as comfortable developing using JS, and I am scared that when the project will become really big I will have troubles maintaining it, and I will get "spaghetti code".
Basically I wanted to know what are the benefits of React over GWT? and am I right to be scared of big scale projects developed in JS?

Comment: Have you tried "typed" JS using TypeScript or Flow? Otherwise look at Scala React, i have heard good things about it but never tried it myself. https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react Im a C# .Net man myself so i use TypeScript with React. I have buildt several very large application with it and it works great. As with all coding you can always create spaghetti, but typescript has helped us a lot when our teams grow.

Comment: I do the same exercise every year :)  I like everything about React and Angular in their "Quick start" and medium-level tutorials, but for larger apps everything gets much more complicated very quickly. There is a trade-off between the flexibility (lots of libraries that you can use without any wrappers) vs the convenience of GWT just providing everything (type safety, EventBus, Activities, Constants (i18n), etc.)

Comment: This is not really a React vs GWT situation: https://github.com/GWTReact

Comment: @PerSvensson, I heard about typescript, but never tried it, maybe it's time to check it out. And I never heard about the combination of Scala and React, I will definitely check it out, thanks!

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, I totally agree with you, that is exactly what I am talking about...

Comment: @ThomasBroyer, I definitely need to check it out, it might be the exact combination I am looking for, thanks!

Comment: React and GWT are different cases IMHO. React is a framework that covers complete UI/UX needs - all the MVP does (kind of). But GWT is a framework that is perfect for M and P in MVP. Visual component support in GWT is quite awful, and as far as I know their plans are to drop support of built-in visual components and to use [Polymer](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/polymer-tutorial/introduction.html) instead. (However I prefer [GWT Material](https://github.com/GwtMaterialDesign/gwt-material)). I believe if you use Java on server side - use GWT. In case of Node.js - use React.

Comment: The GWT Material project looks great, but I still didn't have a chance to use it.
@domax , I like your observation "if you use Java on server side - use GWT. In case of Node.js - use React", it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I use Google Polymer on top of GWT. Pretty sure you can use React components on top of GWT. In my view GWT is the BEST EVER thing which happened to developers who need to write Desktop Quality BUSINESS APPLICATIONS. I heard criticism of GWT but that is coming from architects who don't understand GWT. One needs to learn GWT before writing apps with unexceptable compile times and blaming it on GWT.

Comment: @vitalygoji goji , I agree with you, but if you look at the jobs market, GWT is not really popular right now, most of the jobs are for JS based frameworks, that was one of the reasons I asked this question...

Comment: Just give them what they want and by the time they (slowly) develop their product, develop similar products with superior and faster technology and sell it to their competition:)

Comment: I think nothing is more "spaghetti" than server generated HTML. HTML is "client" and should be generated in the client. Server should not generate anything other than JSON for modern apps. What makes you feel confident in JAVA is that server components generally support backward compatibility when they update to newer versions. Most client libraries don't. They can deprecate the backbone features just like that. Then you end up with either using a not maintained library or constantly fixing something that's not really broken.

Answer (score 1):

Now you could try VueGWT: [Github project](https://github.com/Axellience/vue-gwt)
The idea is to write your control in Java and your views with vueJS templates. We have started (only a few part for now) to use it for [GenMyModel](https://www.genmymodel.com), a very big GWT application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a java born developper who now works in react-redux and miss the object language. If you try to develop a real good application you will have to add redux to react but its pattern is quite weird and not well documented.

If you feel more comfortable with Java than JS you should use GWT. It's true that ag-grid with infinite loading for example, may not exist in GWT for the moment but you have Google support. If you want the latest amazing widgets (the react virtualized select is another example) for your app and you really need them you will have to document yourself about these (with lacks of documentation) and use react.

Comment: Actually since I posted the question I started working with pure JS (hopefully we will move to react soon), and I have more control on the UI structure but I definitely miss the GWT easy development with properly reusable widgets.
About the Google support, GWT is not supported by Google for a long time now but there are projects like GWTP that are constantly supported (not by Google).

Comment: Redux is not well documented? It has one of the best and easiest to understand documentations I've ever seen. I've learnt Redux solely by that documentation plus Egghead videos. The reason you find it quite weird is that being a Java developer you're more used to imperative programming rather than declarative. It makes Redux harder to understand if you still think in Java.

Comment: I think that compared to java or javascript, ressources for redux are quite limited